# Json parsing vs xml parsing?

Tags: xml, json

What are the advantage and disadvantage of json parsing? 
Why developers prefer to use json over xml parsing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536893/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-xml-and-json

Comment: xml parsing requires a preprocessing parser to be written to get data in iPhone readable format. But json objects can be easily read by iPhone Library objects.

Comment: @VimalVenugopalan exactly! +1

Comment: You can see how faster to parse and easier to use JSON than XML here: [Benchmarking( JSON vs XML )](http://www.navioo.com/ajax/ajax_json_xml_Benchmarking.php)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Json...

has a smaller overhead comparred to XML - XML's closing tags increase boilerplate code size by a factor of about 2. It's also more human-readable - consider

```
{
  "key": "value",
  "other key": 3.1415926535897932,
  "arr": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ]
}
```

versus

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- not to mention the DTD declaration -->
<myXmlFormat>
  <key>value</key>
  <otherKey>3.1415926535897932</otherKey>
  <arr>
    <number>1</number>
    <number>2</number>
    <number>3</number>
  </arr>
</myXmlFormat>
```

Is easier and quicker to parse (as it's more lightweight) - there are a lot of JSON parsers which are themselves smaller and quicker than their XML parser counterparts in the same programming language (consider libxml2 versus js0n).

JSON's data types also have a 1:1 mapping to data types traditionally considered "primitive" - such as strings, intergal and real numbers, arrays ans key-value tables. Furthermore, these primitive data types are easy to use with Foundation aa they're built into it - the above JSON can effortlessly parsed to an NSDictionary containing "key", "other key" and "arr" as keys, which correspond to the string "value", pi as an NSNumber and an NSArray, respoectively. Meanwhile XML has to be thought of additionally - maybe you have to even create custom classes to represent your own data structure described in the XML.

Specifically for the iOS platform: Cocoa's native XML parser, NSXMLParser is more than counterintuitive to use. The Foundation framework on iOS doesn't include the NSXMLNode class from Foundation on Mac OS X, and this forces developers to write their own spaghetto code to wrap all the XML to some structured data... well... structure instead of being able to use the included ones.

Comment: I find it easier to understand xml.

Comment: JSON doesn't map directly to XML, which is definitely more complex - but not just about "boilerplate", it's also more flexible and better suited for other things (such as UI). You could represent the same thing with <myXmlFormat key="value" otherKey="3.14159..." /> (except for the array). Both JSON and XML have their uses.

Answer (score 2):

## XML

#### Advantages

- The most important advantage of XML is that it's the most easily readable format for other humans.
- A secondary advantage is that XML has been around for quite a while and that many developers are already accustomed to it.

#### Disadvantages

- The JavaScript required to insert the data into the HTML page is quite verbose.

### JSON

#### Advantages

- The most important advantage is that JSON circumvents JavaScript's same-source policy, if you import the JSON file as a new  tag. See Simon Willison's example for the gory details. JavaScript does not allow you to access documents (be they XML or HTML) that come from another server. However, if you import a JSON file as a script tag you circumvent this problem, and any JSON data can be imported into any website. It depends on your business goals whether this is a Good or a Bad Thing, but right now it's the only data format that allows unrestricted access.
- A secondary advantage is that scripts for JSON data are slightly simpler and slightly more in line with the rest of the JavaScript language than scripts for XML data.

#### Disadvantages

- The most important disadvantage of JSON is that the format is very hard to read for humans, and that, of course, every single comma, quote, and bracket should be in exactly the correct place. While this is also true of XML, JSON's welter of complicated-looking syntax, like the }}]} at the end of the data snippet, may frighten the newbies and make for complicated debugging.

From the comments, JSON is considered faster to process than XML.

Comment: Can not agree at all with the pro XML args!

Comment: Importing json as javascript source is a massive security hole, it is on par with parsing json through the eval function. It works, but is a bad idea.

Comment: Both advantages of XML and disadvantages of JSON are completely opposite, and even advantage of JSON is wrong as it does not circumvent CORS

Comment: Did you mean: "[XML] is the most easily readable format for other **creatures than** humans." ;)